# When I invoke python script with a print statement in it, SCons generates a corrupt target

Tags: scons

I'm a bit confused about how to build from Python script or why SCons doesn't build correctly.

A silly but minimal (not) working example:

I have a Python script, **plot.py**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1 ) 
ax.plot([0,1,2], [10,20,3])
print 'Doing some stuff...'
fig.savefig('figure.png')
```

If I run the script in terminal `$ python plot.py` it creates a nice image file but if invoke the script from SCons, it creates a corrupt file that can't be opened. However, it seems to have the same size as it should.

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
env.Command('figure.png', 'plot.py', 'python $SOURCE > $TARGET')
```

If I specify target as `$ scons figure.png` the result is the same. Cleaning and rebuilding (`scons -c`) doesn't help. I get no Error message.

```
$ scons
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
python plot.py > figure.png
scons: done building targets.
```

A debug looks OK, as far as I can tell:

```
+-.
  +-SConstruct
  +-figure.png
  | +-plot.py
  | +-/Users/tobiasstal/anaconda/bin/python
  +-plot.py
```

But, interestingly enough, if I remove the `print` statement it works.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time

fig, ax = plt.subplots( nrows=1, ncols=1 ) 
ax.plot([0,1,2], [10,20,3])
time.sleep(3)
# print 'Doing some stuff...'
fig.savefig('figure.png')
```

Also if I run the Python script above directly in the SConstruct file it saves the figure correctly.

What do I do wrong? How do I invoke a Python script from SCons to generate a working target, even if there is a print statement in the script?

Using OS 10.11.6
Python 2.7
SCons 2.5.0

Comment: You say that the target `figure.png` is corrupt after the build step, but what are the actual input files for this step? So far, your script `plot.py` creates it from scratch...so if the resulting file is corrupt you shouldn't blame SCons for it. ;) Also note that with the given dependencies as above, you'll only see a rebuild of `figure.png` if `plot.py` changes its content. Finally, what happens when you specify an intermediate target like `figure.png` on the command line explicitly with `scons figure.png`?

Comment: @dirkbaechle  I'm not blaming SCons, I'm rather sure that it is a user mistake... I've updated the question as I realized that I could make a more concentrated example. In a real project, the python script would have an input data but the problem is the same even if the script just building something from scratch. Specifying intermediate target gives the same result. Interestingly, it seems as it only happens if there is a `print` statement in the python script, something that I can't really avoid for the real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your python script writes to the target and then you create output which gets redirected to the same target, it's not surprising you get a corrupt file...

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
env.Command('figure.png', 'plot.py', 'python $SOURCE > $TARGET')
```

You can either omit "> $TARGET" from the command string. Or modify your script to take an argument which is the target file and change your SCons logic to be

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
env.Command('figure.png', 'plot.py', 'python $SOURCE $TARGET')
```